# Factoring 3 Dimensional Polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

How do you factor a system of polynomials into their roots the way one can factor a single dimensional polynomial into its roots.

Example

$$x^2 + y^2 = 14$$

$$xy = 1$$

We note that we can find the 4 solutions via quadratic formula and substitution such that the solutions can be separated into $2$ groups of $2$ such that each group lies on either $(x + y + 4)$ and $(x + y - 4)$. Note that:

$$(x + y + 4)(x + y - 4) = 0$$

$$xy = 1$$

Is also an equivalent system.

How do I factor the bottom half?

Ideally if $g$ is a linear expression then my system should be

$$g_1 * g_2 = 0$$

$$g_3 * g_4 = 0$$

Such that the solutions to

Any of the subsystems of this system is a solution to system itself (note there are $4$ viable subsystems).

Help?

Comment: So I have worked a bit more on the system and found that:

Comment: x = 2 + sqrt(3), x = 2 - sqrt(3), x = -2 + sqrt(3), x = -2 - sqrt(3), are the four x solutions with corresponding y. The system is equivalent to:

Comment: (x + y + 4)(x + y - 4) = 0 & (x - y - 2sqrt(3))(x - y + 2sqrt(3)) = 0

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you have a bunch of equations in several variables and want to solve them simultaneously, you should not think of *factoring* as the basic method but rather *elimination of variables*, one by one. For a different example, take the circle $x^2+y^2=2$ and the ellipse $x^2-xy+y^2=1$. You expect four intersections, if you count them properly anyway. Subtract the equations and get the third relation $xy=1$, and substitute $y=1/x$ into (for instance) the first equation, which becomes $x^4-2x^2+1=0$ after clearing the fractions. This is $(x^2-1)^2=0$, as you see, and now, *in the last step*, you factor, to see that the points $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ are the only intersection points, but that they occur with multiplicity two.

Answer (score 1):

For the "example" you list, here are some suggestions: Given

$$x^2 + y^2 = 14\tag{1}$$
$$xy = 1 \iff y = \frac 1x\tag{2}$$

- Substitute $y = \dfrac{1}{x}\tag{*}$ into equation $(1)$. Then solve for roots of the resulting equation in one variable.

$$x^2 + y^2 = 14\tag{a}$$

$$\iff x^2 + \left(\frac 1x\right)^2 = 14\tag{b}$$

$$\implies x^4 - 14x^2 + 1 = 0\tag{c}$$

Try letting $z = x^2$ and solve the resulting quadratic:

$$z^2 - 14z + 1 = 0\tag{d}$$ Then for each root $z_1, z_2,\;$ there will be two repeated roots solving $(c)$: $2 \times 2$ repeated roots

Notice that by incorporating the equation (2) into equation  step $(b)$, we effectively end up finding all solutions that satisfy both equations $(1), (2)$: solutions for which the two given equations coincide.

See Lubin's post for some additional "generalizations": ways to approach problems such as this.

Comment: This is the method I had used earlier. I didn't find it appealing at the time since the problem becomes exponentially more difficult to solve as equation degree and variable count is increased...

Comment: Do you suppose there is some way to divide out the roots the way one does when factoring a normal 1-dimensional polynomial?

Comment: The best way, with this given example, is to use the quadratic formula to find the roots of the equation in $z$: there are two real roots, but they will involve a radical (square root sign): $z = 7 \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{285}}{2}$, so those will be the roots for $(c)$, but each will be repeated.

Comment: Does this make sense? In this case, the "fourth degree" polynomial can be treated as a quadratic equation, which greatly simplifies the factoring/solution-finding!

Answer (score 0):

If you have equations of the form $p(x, y) = 0$ where $p$ is a polynomial, factoring that one is certainly worthwhile, It will give you more equations, but simpler ones. So, if you have:
$$
\begin{align*}
(x + y) (x^2 - y^2) &= 0 \\
(x - y) (x^2 + y^2) &= 0
\end{align*}
$$
you end up with $2 \times 2 = 4$ (pick one from each) systems of equations.

But if factoring polynomials in one variable isn't a walk in the park, with more variables it just gets worse.